# Unable to filter on class name (in NLog.config) when using anotar catel nlog logging

Tags: nlog, catel, fody

I am using anotar catel fody for logging in my application.

In NLog.config I want to use different levels for certain classes. Example config

```
<logger name="SpaceA.*"
        minlevel="Info"
        writeTo="file"
        final="true" />
<logger name="*"
        minlevel="Debug"
        writeTo="file" />
```

I have created a NLogListener class which derives from catel's LogListenerBase.

```
public class NLogListener : LogListenerBase
{
    private static readonly NLog.Logger Log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    protected override void Debug(ILog log, string message, object extraData)
    {
        Log.Debug(message);
    }

    protected override void Info(ILog log, string message, object extraData)
    {
        Log.Info(message);
    }

    protected override void Warning(ILog log, string message, object extraData)
    {
        Log.Warn(message);
    }

    protected override void Error(ILog log, string message, object extraData)
    {
        Log.Error(message);
    }
    #endregion Methods
}
```

In my code I use Catel Anotar Fody:

```
LogTo.Debug("Starting something...");
```

Now no matter where I use the logging, it is all being displayed as coming from the namespace where I have defined the LogListerer.

What am I doing wrong and ergo do I have to change to be able to filter the NLog on class names like it normally should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you get the current class logger in the LogListener:

```
private static readonly NLog.Logger Log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

That way, you always log to the NLogListener type. What you should do is get the right logger type for each entry:

```
protected override void Debug(ILog log, string message, object extraData)
{
    var nlog = NLog.LogManager.GetClassLogger(log.TargetType);
    nlog.Debug(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Geert, that makes sense :)

However when I do this I run into the following error when calling NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(log.TargetType):

"Cannot access the constructor of type: VES.Framework.AppDomainExtensions. Is the required permission granted?"

This seems to occur if I have log message calls in a static class.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Okay, changing the call to GetLogger(log.TargetType.ToString()) did the trick :)